# Error in adding parts to the question

Tags: errors

I am new to Latex and trying to add parts to main question by using \begin{parts}.
When I run my code, I get the error "!LaTeX error: Environment parts undefined"

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\def\convw #1{\mathop{\rightarrow}\limits^{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,fancyhdr,enumerate}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}

\section*{}
\subsection*{Problem 1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Conditional Probabilty
\begin{parts}
\part marginal probability density.
\part posterior density
\end{parts}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong. Do I need to include any specific package for it.

Comment: Do you work in the exam class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you wanted to use the `exam` class, where the environment `parts` is defined.

MWE

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\section*{}
\subsection*{Problem 1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Conditional Probabilty
\begin{parts}
\part marginal probability density.
\part posterior density
\end{parts}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

otherwise substitute

```
\begin{parts}
\part marginal probability density.
\part posterior density
\end{parts}
```

with

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item marginal probability density.
\item posterior density
\end{enumerate}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\def\convw #1{\mathop{\rightarrow}\limits^{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,fancyhdr,enumerate}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\section*{}
\subsection*{Problem 1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Conditional Probabilty
\begin{enumerate}
\item marginal probability density.
\item posterior density
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]